# 'Filter by condition' Google Spreadsheet, filter by both included and excluded text

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to use the filter by condition filter to a the same time show text that contains the word "topic" but not the word "view".

For instance `example.com/topic` would be shown, but `example.com/view/lorem/topic` wouldnt be shown. Is that possible to do ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to Filter by condition > Custom formula is :

`=AND(SEARCH("topic",A:A),ISERROR(SEARCH("view",A:A)))`

I suspect there might be a way of using a REGEXMATCH formula too